# How can I inspect the contents of an add-on panel in Firefox's Inspector?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am authoring an add-on for Firefox that generates a panel when the user clicks the button in the add-on bar.

In Chrome, my popup renders the way that I want it to, but I can right-click on the popup and select "Inspect element" from the context menu to debug the rendering.

In Firefox, the panel is rendering strangely, but right-clicking on it doesn't give me a context menu. Selecting Debug from the add-on tab allows me to see the content scripts and set breakpoints, but no Inspector there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "inspect element" in chrome is probably visible while you are in developer mode right?

I'm not sure about the firefox inspector yet, but it is possible using:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/

and then an addon for this inspector called:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/

This addon really enables catching context menus and other temporally displayed elements. Shift + Right click and it will popup in inspector.

This DOM INspector is how we used to do it before firefox devtools came up. I'm sure there is a way, I just havent explored it too much yet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This does work, but the DOM Inspector plugin is nowhere near as full-featured as I was hoping for. I'm trying to figure out placement and sizing issues, and that inspector only gives very simple hierarchy and specified attributes information. At least I can see that the DOM is being generated correctly.

Comment: @danBhentschel click on the drop down and go to css, its actual super powerful. can even get into the xbl :) even live edits on anonymous elements. its superb. but you cant see attached events like the firefox tools, that is a super awesome feature of firefox tools

Comment: Thanks. you are correct. I didn't notice that drop-down. I am now able to inspect details in the popup.